# Magente error 503 without maintenance.flag file

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I am facing the error 503 as well on live.

It has happened when I manually made the maintenance.flag file - which is correct.

Then I deleted that file but the error 503 is still present. I deleted www/var/cache and session but still the error 503 present.

Then I made the trial to clear the following lines in index.php

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(**FILE**) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

Error still present.

I went on my developement environment and put a maintenance.flag file. Got the error 503.

I cleared the lines above in index.php and it cleared the error 503 which makes sense.

I put back the lines within index and cleared maintenance.flag. Error disappeared correctly.

I swapped my live and dev database to see if it was not stored there but still error present.

I am getting crazy with a live environment not working for my e-commerce site...

Comment: Are you using a cache within or in front of your webserver? What happens when you remove index.php temporarily?

Comment: are you using files for cache? if you are using redis for instance or something else then deleting var/cache has no effect